# Windows Storage Spaces folder disappers after copying into it

Tags: windows, data-recovery, storage, storage-spaces

I created a new Windows 10 ReFS Storage Spaces drive with two brand new 4TB HDD-s (as mirrors). I filled the space with lots of data. Everything worked as expected.

I tried to copy one file by using drag and drop in Explorer into a folder on the storage space from an another drive. After the "copy" the folder simply became inaccessible. Entering the folder gave a "no permisson" error. Then I tried to access it using administrator rights, but no lock. After restarting the computer the folder is gone. It's not hidden (hidden files are shown). The storage space looks "green".

What could have happened here??!!

SMART info:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What folder. destination folder? You dropped file in folder on storage space after which this folder becomes inaccessible and disappears?

Comment: Exactly. Makes no sense at all. Never seen such behaviour before.

Comment: To be precise, it did not disappear. It just became inaccessible first, impossible to open. Then after restart it just did not show up anymore. A folder with cca. 100GB data.

Comment: I can't find the used space using WinDirStat either. That amount of data should be visible.  I thought maybe I accidentally moved it into another folder.

Comment: I hope you have good backups for all your data, because this doesn't look good. Please include in your question the SMART attributes of the two disks.

Comment: Fortunately the data has backups. It's just harder to trust the new storage, when something like this happens...